# How to avoid checking each condition inside if statement which contains complex operation

Tags: performance, syntax

Let's say I have this code:

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
    some_complex_operation(); // memory or time wise, doesn't matter
    if (condition1) {
        doJob1();
    }
    if (condition2) {
        doJob2();
    }
}
```

Now of course normal procedure here would be to leave out the first if condition, but since I want my complex operation to happen only when one of conditions is satisfied I'd want to avoid doing it every time.

Is there syntactically better way to rewrite this part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the check for your conditions is expensive, I think your code is fine as it is (and if the check is expensive, you could convert them into booleans before the first `if`).

Alternatives would be:

- move the call to the complex operation inside both `if`'s and remove the outer `if`, but I like it better as it is now, because it's in one block.
- depending on the values of your conditions, you could use a `switch` statement instead of the two `if`'s, but that won't make much of a difference.

If both conditions can't be true at the same time you could place an `else` before the second inner `if`. You could even remove the second check and only use `else` but then you'd have to make sure the number of conditions never changes.

And of course, in general with `or`, always place the condition that occurs the most first (in both cases) so there's no need to check the second condition when the first evaluates to `true`.